# Best way to get item count by filter in a big list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, rest, ajax

I have a list of ~11000 items.

Now lets say I have a multi-choice field in that list, and would like to find out how many items of each choice there are (using REST API or JSOM).

Multi-choice fields cannot be indexed, and even if it could, it wouldn't work if the query returns more than 5000 items (I have ~9000 items with "Option A" in that list).

What do you think would be the best solution to work around this?
Multiple queries? Additional properties? Views?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please try below REST API method for getting count for particular choice.
_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Fruits/$count?$filter=((color eq 'red'))

Comment: @Sam doesn't work :/